# NoClassDefFoundError but class is present

Tags: java, command-line

My Jar file

```
  cassandra-driver-core-2.1.0.jar
```

My Javap command for `com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster`

```
  javap -classpath cassandra-driver-core-2.1.0.jar com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster
```

It shows

```
 public class com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster implements java.io.Closeable {
 final com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager manager;
 protected com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster(java.lang.String, java.util.List<java.net.InetSocketAddress>, com.datastax.driver.core.Configuration);
 protected com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster(com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Initializer);
 public com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster init();
 public static com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster buildFrom(com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Initializer);
 public static com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder builder();
 ...............
```

My Java file is

```
 import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
 import com.datastax.driver.core.Host;
 import com.datastax.driver.core.Metadata;

 public class SimpleClient {
    private Cluster cluster;

    public void connect(String node) {
       System.out.println("I am in");
       cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(node).build(); 
       //ERROR
 }

 public void close() {
   cluster.close();
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SimpleClient client = new SimpleClient();
   System.out.println("Obj Created");
  client.connect("127.0.0.1");
 // client.close();
  }
 }
```

My compile command is

```
   javac -classpath cassandra-driver-core-2.1.0.jar SimpleClient.java
```

My Run command

```
   tried1:   java  -classpath cassandra-driver-core-2.1.0.jar SimpleClient
```

Says

```
  Could not find or load main class SimpleClient
```

But class is present.

```
  Tried2:  java  -classpath SimpleClient
```

It says

```
  Obj Created
  I am in
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster
    at SimpleClient.connect(SimpleClient.java:12)
    at SimpleClient.main(SimpleClient.java:29)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster
```

Please let me know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
java  -classpath ./;cassandra-driver-core-2.1.0.jar SimpleClient
```

on a windows machine

or

```
java  -classpath ./:cassandra-driver-core-2.1.0.jar SimpleClient
```

on a linux machine.

This will add the actual directory to your classpath.